# How to edit columns values based on another value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement

My data fame looks like this:

```
val    type
10     new
70     new
61     new
45     old
32     new
77     mid
11     mid
```

For values  in column "type", if value is new, I want to edit it depending on val column. If value in val is =< 20, it must be new-1, if > 20 and  < 50, it must be new-2,if >= 50, it must be new-3. So desired result is:

```
val    type
10     new-1
70     new-3
61     new-3
45     old
32     new-2
77     mid
11     mid
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pd.cut`:

```
>>> df['type'] = df['type'].where(df['type'].ne('new'), df['type'] + '-' + pd.cut(df['val'], [0, 20, 50, float('inf')], labels=[1, 2, 3]).astype(str))
>>> df
   val   type
0   10  new-1
1   70  new-3
2   61  new-3
3   45    old
4   32  new-2
5   77    mid
6   11    mid
>>>
```

Comment: I edited my question a little but, it was wrong. it must be ```If value in val is =< 20, it must be new-1, if > 20 and < 50, it must be new-2,if >= 50, it must be new-3```

Comment: @skulldoger Yes, then make `20` to be `21`. and `50` should be `49` I guess

Comment: @skulldoger Edited my answer with working code